# How is MaxHeapSize determined when packaging a JVM executable using the maven-assembly-plugin?

Tags: jvm, maven-assembly-plugin

This may be the only example I've seen where one doesn't have to specify the maximum heap size by some means (or accept a rather low default MaxHeapSize); my application is easily able to consume memory on my system on the order of multiple gigabytes without me specifying `-Xmx`, as far as I can tell).

My current configuration looks like the following:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>${os}</classifier>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>edu.cornell.ansci.dairy.econ.ui.MainWindow</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```